# Apache and Perl

Tags: apache, perl

I am trying to get OpenDLP to work on my system. For those not familiar with this, only think of it as a perl website.

I mostly prepared everything, except that UI gives errors.

After some digging and debugging, I found out that my Perl scripts are running under directory '/'! And when pages try to read '../etc/db_admin' they won't find it and throw error.

My vhost config for this ui:

```
<VirtualHost opendlp.local:443>
    ServerAdmin vahid.fazl2000@engineer.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/vahid/Downloads/OpenDLP-0.5.1/OpenDLP/web/bin"
    ServerName opendlp.local:443
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/opendlp-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/opendlp-access_log" common

    Include conf/extra/httpd-opendlp.conf

    <Directory "/home/vahid/Downloads/OpenDLP-0.5.1/OpenDLP/web/bin">
               AddHandler perl-script .pl .html
               PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry
               Options +ExecCGI
               PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
               AllowOverride All
               Options All
               Require method GET POST OPTIONS
    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

and here is httpd.opendlp.conf

```
Alias /OpenDLP/images/ /home/vahid/Downloads/OpenDLP-0.5.1/OpenDLP/web/bin/images
<Directory "/home/vahid/Downloads/OpenDLP-0.5.1/OpenDLP/web/bin/images/">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
        #AuthType Basic                                                                                                                               
        #AuthName "OpenDLP"                                                                                                                           
        #AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd.dlp.user                                                                                                 
        #Require user dlpuser                                                                                                                         
</Directory>
ScriptAlias /OpenDLP/ "/home/vahid/Downloads/OpenDLP-0.5.1/OpenDLP/web/bin/"
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/home/vahid/Downloads/OpenDLP-0.5.1/OpenDLP/web/bin/"
<Directory "/home/vahid/Downloads/OpenDLP-0.5.1/OpenDLP/web/bin/results/">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
        #AuthType Basic                                                                                                                               
        #AuthName "OpenDLP"                                                                                                                           
        #AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd.dlp.agent                                                                                                
        #Require user ddt                                                                                                                             
</Directory>
<Directory "/home/vahid/Downloads/OpenDLP-0.5.1/OpenDLP/web/bin/">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
        #AuthType Basic                                                                                                                               
        #AuthName "OpenDLP"                                                                                                                           
        #AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd.dlp.user                                                                                                 
        #Require user dlpuser                                                                                                                         
</Directory>

#Also add this stuff to the Apache config file:                                                                                                       
# taken from http://hausheer.osola.com/docs/9                                                                                                         
SSLEngine on
#SSLVerifyClient require                                                                                                                              
SSLCertificateFile /home/vahid/Downloads/OpenDLP-0.5.1/OpenDLP/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/vahid/Downloads/OpenDLP-0.5.1/OpenDLP/server.key
SSLCACertificateFile /home/vahid/Downloads/OpenDLP-0.5.1/OpenDLP/server.crt
```

I haven't tried Perl for web before, and I am not familiar with mod_perl and its options. I have googled for this, but it seems that I don't know where to look (except here, of course :-) )

BTW, I'm on Arch Linux x64 if it matters.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Here is some more info on errors.
This is the error I get when I visit `https://opendlp.local/profiles-manage.html`

```
No such file or directory at /home/vahid/Downloads/OpenDLP-0.5.1/OpenDLP/web/bin/profiles-manage.html line 29.
```

And here is line 29 (and around it) of file:

```
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use DBI;
use Cwd qw();


my $version = get_version();
my $db_admin_file = "../etc/db_admin";
my( $db_username, $db_password ) = "";
open( DB, $db_admin_file ) or die $!;  # LINE 29
my $db_line = <DB>;
close( DB );
chomp $db_line;
($db_username, $db_password) = split( ":", $db_line );


header();
print "<heading>Manage existing scan profiles</heading><normal><br><br>\n";
```

I have added `use Cwd` myself (googled, actually) and checked working directory, which is `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Change DocumentRoot to

> /home/vahid/Downloads/OpenDLP-0.5.1/OpenDLP/web

instead of

> /home/vahid/Downloads/OpenDLP-0.5.1/OpenDLP/web/bin"

Then in your script:

```
my $db_admin_file = "etc/db_admin";
```

You have "cannot find file" error because your code runs on a virtual host where the directory you set as Document Root is regarded as root directory (/). You cannot "go behind" a root directory,

Comment: I Know that, but if I wanted to do that I also have to change every script. Isn't there a way to tell `mod_perl` to use script's directory as cwd? There should be a way

Comment: I did this, and it didn't work. I figured out that `/` actually meant my root partition, because when I copied `db_admin` to `/etc` everything worked!